# Import python object properties into current scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an object with interesting properties, like a command line parsed via `ArgumentParser`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.add_argument('a')
parser.add_argument('b')
parser.add_argument('--with-c')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.a, args.b, args.with_c)
```

The question is applicable in general, not only to `Namespace` returned by `ArgumentParser`.

I would like to use `a`, `b` and `with_c` directly in the scope after parsing the command line to `args`, without prefixing them with `args.`

Is it possible to do something like `from args import *`?

Comment: `import this`: *"[...] Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"* Anyway you can't import from an object, the only option to realize this is by putting your parser into its own module, then do the manual unpacking over there and then use the import syntax as a shorthand. But it's really not nice. Namespaces *are* a great idea.

Comment: The most you can do is `a = args.a ; b = args.b ; with_c = args.with_c` then you can use them without the `args`

Comment: @Tomerikoo, that's what I do but it's cumbersome and I'm searching for a better alternative

Comment: @Tomerikoo Or `a, b, with_c = args.a, args.b, args.with_c`, or DRYer, `a, b, with_c = [getattr(args, x) for x in ['a', 'b', 'with_c']]`

Comment: @ragazzojp just use `args`. That's *the best alternative*.